# truncated inverse mellin transform of reciprocal gamma?

Tags: calculus, integration, mellin-transform

I'm studying the function: $\int_0^t \frac{x^{ir}}{\Gamma(1+ir)} dr$

where $0<x<\infty$. This integral doesn't converge when $t = \infty$. This integral came up when I was trying to integrate $\zeta(1+it)$ with respect to $t$.

Can anything be said about this integral?